# xamarin android SipManager different success on different devices

Tags: android, xamarin.android, voip

i'm using the SipManager API on xamarin (android) to register with a voip provider
The following code works perfectly on one device (i can even make a call) and throws an exception on a different device.

I understand not everything will support this, but i am already checking if *IsVoipSupported*.

what more should i check ?

Or is there a different reason why the register call doesn't work on one device ?

**code**:

```
if (SipManager.IsApiSupported(Application.Context) &&
    SipManager.IsVoipSupported(Application.Context))
{
    logstuff("Registring with sip server");
    sipmanager = SipManager.NewInstance(Application.Context);

    SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("0123456", "sip00.mynetfone.com.au");
    builder.SetPassword("*******"); // sorry, not sharing :)


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.SetAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent, (Android.App.PendingIntentFlags)Android.Content.FillInFlags.Data);

    this.sipProfileLocal = builder.Build();
    regListnener = new MyRegistrationListener();
    sipmanager.Open(this.sipProfileLocal);
    sipmanager.Register(this.sipProfileLocal, 100, regListnener);
    sipmanager.SetRegistrationListener(this.sipProfileLocal.UriString, regListnener);

}
else
{
     logstuff("This device does not support VoIP !! )");
}
```

**exception**:

```
 Android.Net.Sip.SipException: SipService.createSession() returns null
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/f3074d2c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11643 
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:26 
at Android.Net.Sip.SipManager.Register (Android.Net.Sip.SipProfile localProfile, System.Int32 expiryTime, Android.Net.Sip.ISipRegistrationListener listener) [0x0006e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-25/src/generated/Android.Net.Sip.SipManager.cs:479 
at voiptry1.MainActivity.Register_Click (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x000af] in E:\projects\voip-research\voiptry1-xamarin-working-tom\voiptry1\MainActivity.cs:173 
--- End of managed Android.Net.Sip.SipException stack trace ---
android.net.sip.SipException: SipService.createSession() returns null
at android.net.sip.SipManager.register(SipManager.java:492)
at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10573)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6914)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Did you check the network of your phone?`SipService.createSession()` can also returns null if there is no internet.

Comment: yes. sadly it does. when i install a different voip program it can register (to the same voip provider) and make calls..so i know it's not even a tablet/phone issue ...